# Turn drag and drop ordering SQL compatible

Tags: mysql, sorting, mariadb, columnsorting

I have a page that has a lot of items, and it could be reordered by drag and drop, modifying a column on this item called `order` (integer). To order on this page, I do something like `` ORDER BY `order` ASC ``.

**Process works like that (during a drag n drop):**

1. Identify the `order` value from the target item (dropped at);
2. Update the `order` value of source item to same as target item;
3. Increase the `order` value of the target item by one;
4. Query if another item on the table has the same `order` than target item;

   1. If true, increase the `order` of this item by one;
   2. Repeat step 5 until does not exists items with the same `order` value;

At the end of the process, the source item will stay on top of the target item.

The problem with that process is that it runs 2 updates + N times (1 query and 1 update), depending on how much the order will conflict after initial update. So in a table with 1.000.000 of items with an order from 1 to 1.000.000, if I move an item with order 1 to 5, for instance, it will run almost two million queries.

---

My current solution is to use an `order` as float or double. Then when I insert a value on the table, I set the `order` to same as `id` of the item.

**Then the process works like that:**

1. Identify the `order` value from target item (dropped at) -- eg. 503;
2. Query the first item that has `order` immediately lower than `order` of target item -- e.g., 502;
3. Update the `order` value of source item to avg of both values -- e.g., 502,5;

It will work fine, but with a big amount of data it will conflict in some moment and will be hard to identify or fix this conflict.

---

**My question is:** there some more reliable and fast method that allows handle items are ordering on the table that could work better than a float column?

Comment: In your Javascript on the page, as a row is moved (re-ordered) update an array with the new order number, and increment the following items in the array by one. The array should contain the id of the item, and the order value. To update, send the entire array to the server, and update by id.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thanks, but it will not works if some filter is applied on page via server side. For instance, I could query "users with more than 18 years old" then sort it, because the JS will be able just to update visible itens, and not itens that not matches with the filter.

Comment: If the displayed list isn't in order by the ```order``` column, then drag'n'drop ordering isn't appropriate. The problem is that if you move an item, what about the in-between items, IOW, the ones not displayed?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The 'order' of the data set, and the 'order' of the result set seem to be two entirely unrelated things.

Comment: @SloanThrasher the displayed list **is** in order by the `order` column, but at same time, this list could not display all rows of table due to an (optional) filter. For instance, I have "Item 1", "2", "3", "4" and "5", but I could apply a "odd filtering", so will display only "1", "3" and "5", and I could move "5" to top of "3", so the internal ordering (without filter) will be "1", "2", "5", "3" and "4".

Comment: By "in order", I mean no gaps in the ordering value.